# Python test patch is never called

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, pygithub

I am trying to test with my code by mocking the PyGithub library.
I want to create a repository for an organization. So first I need to get it and on the "Organization" returned object, I need to make another call.

It fails when trying to assert that my second method was called.

I am very new to python and I am guessing that there is a missing connection between the mocks but I cannot figure out what.

```py
class GithubService:
    def __init__(self, token: str) -> None:
        self.__github__ = Github(token)
        self.__token__ = token

    def create_repo_extra(self, repo_name, description, organization_name, team_name):
        try:
            organization = self.__github__.get_organization(organization_name)
            repo = organization.create_repo(name=repo_name,
                                            description=description,
                                            private=True,
                                            has_issues=False,
                                            has_wiki=False,
                                            has_projects=False,
                                            allow_merge_commit=False)
            # do other things with the returned repo.....
            return True
        except GithubException as ex:
            print(ex.data)
            return False
```

Here is the test:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock, ANY

from github.Organization import Organization
from github.Repository import Repository

from src.github_service import GithubService


class TestGithubService(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('github.Organization.Organization.create_repo',
           side_effect=MagicMock(return_value=Repository(ANY, {}, {}, True)))
    @patch('github.MainClass.Github.get_organization',
           return_value=MagicMock(return_value=Organization(ANY, {}, {}, True)))
    def test_create_repo_returns_true(self, get_organization, create_repo):

        sut = GithubService("token")
        actual = sut.create_repo_extra('repo-name', 'description', 'organization-name', 'team-name')

        get_organization.assert_called() # ok
        create_repo.assert_called()      # failed

        self.assertTrue(actual)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mock your `Github.get_organization` you can use the `MagicMock` it returns directly rather than trying to mock another layer.

In this, I patch the same `Github.get_organization`, but avoid giving it a side effect or return value, and therefore pass it as an arg (like you did).

Then I create a convenience `mock_organization` and it will be the return value of the patched `Github.get_organization`.

Finally, the patch is checked like you did, and through the convenience `mock_organization` I check the `create_repo` method is called as well.

```py
class TestGithubService(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("github.MainClass.Github.get_organization")
    def test_create_repo_returns_true(self, mock_get_organization):

        mock_organization = MagicMock()
        mock_get_organization.return_value = mock_organization

        sut = GithubService("token")
        actual = sut.create_repo_extra(
            "repo-name", "description", "organization-name", "team-name"
        )

        mock_get_organization.assert_called()  # ok
        mock_organization.create_repo.assert_called()  # ok

        self.assertTrue(actual)
```

Without seeing more of your code I am not sure why patching `Organization` did not work, but this is simpler, cleaner and just as effective.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I deleted everything and started from scratch and ended up with code very similar to yours